# Delete rows from UITableView and update array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, uitableview, userdefaults

With the tableview I am trying to delete only one record of the list but with my code it deletes all the userDefault data. how do i delete only one record?

```
cell.buttonPressed = {
            
            self.recDictionaryId?["\(title)"] = "\(sentence)"
            
            self.pokemonArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tvPokemon.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(self.pokemonArray, forKey: "UserDefSaveDictionary")

            defaults.synchronize()
            
            self.tvPokemon.reloadData()

}
```

I also tried with:

removeObject(forKey: "UserDefSaveDictionary")

but the result is the same

Comment: Are you sure you trigger buttonPressed when button clicked? Could you please share your Cell class?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .delete {
    objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self. deleteItem(indexPath.row) 
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
}


func deleteItem(_ index: Int) {
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let data =  userDefaults.data(forKey:”keyName”) , var array =  try? JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data) {
    array.remove(at: index)
    guard let result =  try? JSONEncoder().encode(array) else { return }
    userDefaults.set(result, forKey:”keyName”) 
} 
}
```

you have to fetch the UserDefaults response array and convert it to a model then it would be much easier, if you want make this better you can try by adding a completion block to deleteItem() function and inside that you can perform real deletion

Comment: thanks but error: Cannot find 'Model' in scope

Comment: bro, what is the array type you are getting from userdefaults ?